# enum duration question

Tags: java, enums

So if we have an enum like:

```
  public enum light { red, yellow, green }
```

What would be the duration? Isn't it the time the light is a certain color?

Like

```
int duration = ligt.red = 1
```

or something like that?

Comment: Could you describe the data you would like to represent rather than the structure in which you would like to represent it? We can probably better assist if you tell us more about the data/task.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what exactly you're asking - You've given us nothing about the context of the problem, so we don't know what *duration* is supposed to be any more than you do.

Answer (score 3):

Declare your enum like this:

```
public enum Light { 
    RED(1), 
    YELLOW(2), 
    GREEN(3);

    private final int duration;

    Light(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    } 

    public int getDuration() {
        return this.duration;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Light light = Light.RED;
        System.out.println("Duration of RED is: " + light.getDuration());
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Based on Steve Kuo's suggestion, the variable `duration` has been made final.

Comment: You should make `duration` final.

Comment: @Steve Kuo - I don't think so, why?

Comment: So that some idiot doesn't come along later and add a `setDuration()`. Enums should usually be immutable.

Comment: +1 good solution. Steve Kuo and ILMTitan are right about making the field final.

Comment: @Steve Kuo - Absolutely! You're right. I've edited my post :)

Answer (score 0):

Adarshr's answer presumes that duration is a property of the color of the light. If it is instead a property of the color at a particular set of signals, you might use an `EnumMap<light, Integer>`.

```
class Signal {
    private EnumMap<light, Integer> durations = new EnumMap<light, Integer>(light.class);
    Signal() {
        this.durations.put(light.red, 3);
        ....
    }
}
```